# Подсветка текущего пункта меню

Tags: html, jquery, css

Задача стоит в том чтобы текущий пункт меню подсвечивая, но что-то не работает.

Подскажите в чем может быть причина и как её исправить?

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('.ddsmoothmenu a').each(function() {
    if ('http://localhost:8080' + $(this).attr('href') == window.location.href) {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="templatemo_menu" class="ddsmoothmenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Главная</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">О компании</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.html">Новые поступления</a></li>
    <li><a href="faqs.html">Оплата и Доставка</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Контакты</a></li>
    <li><a href="reviews.php">Отзывы</a></li>
    <li><a href="basket.php">Корзина</a></li>

    <?php if (Auth\User::isAuthorized()): ?>
    <li><a href="account.php">Мой кабинет</a></li>
    <?php else: ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
  </ul>
  <br style="clear: left" />
</div>
```

Comment: @entithat Если Вы подскажите как это реализовать, то я буду очень благодарен + с меня галочка

Comment: А если поставить `/` после `http://localhost:8080`?

Comment: @entithat спасибо, мой косяк

Comment: `<br style="clear: left" />`  - это что ?????????)))

Comment: @Air , это минизаготовка на будущее. Представим что под главным меню нужно будет дать какую-то информацию для пользователей, так вот под данным блоком можно разместить всё что угодно и оно будет отображаться корректно. Смотрите здесь полный код (попробуйте удалить блок и посмотреть как изменится) https://jsfiddle.net/jhnerpk5/28/

Comment: Блин, так редко этим тегом пользуюсь, что и забыл про  свойство `clear`

Comment: @Air очень хороший тег. Минимум мороки, максимум эффекта, к тому же использовать его можно по разному. P.S.: можешь помочь с вопросом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

У вас ошибка в том, что в ссылках указан относительный путь, тогда как JS возвращает абсолютный. Исправьте ссылки.

**jQuery**

Данный вариант более гибок:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.ddsmoothmenu a').each(function () {
        var location = window.location.href;
        var link = this.href; 
        if(location == link) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: если добавляю значения для передачи в ссылку то подсветка не работает. Как исправить?